# Убрать активность с текущего элемента и передать только следующему

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, циклы

Моя задача передавать активность предыдущему или следующему элементу по свайпу влево или вправо, в представленном фрагменте кода в консоль выводится только активный элемент и следующий после него, однако при попытке добавить active следующему элементу, он передается ВСЕМ следующим элементам.

```
items.forEach((photo) => {
    if (photo.classList.contains('active')) {
        console.log(photo);
        console.log(photo.nextElementSibling);
        photo.nextElementSibling?.classList.add('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Мне кажется проблема в том, что ты не снимаешь `active` у текущего элемента

Answer (score 0):

Перед

```
photo.nextElementSibling?.classList.add('active');
```

Добавьте

```
photo.classList.remove('active')
```